# How to use MDC's tab bar?

Tags: javascript, html, mdc-components

I want to use this Tab system:

https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/tabs

I read the HTML source code of the above link and implemented a tab bar.

However, how do I switch displayed contents using this tab bar? Do I need to write JavaScript?

Comment: Yeah, it's a JavaScript library, so you have to import their scripts

Comment: Got it working?

Comment: I totally get your question. The documentation says little about how to add content to a tab page. It is pretty unclear if this is possible in a declarative way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a JavaScript library.... so you will need to import the JavaScript.

Firstly you need to install the library, installation instructions can be [found here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/README.md#quick-start).

Next you can proceed to using the tab bar, [following these instructions](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-tab-bar#tab-bar).

Here's a quick working demo to show it's possible, (but I wouldn't recommend using this code)

```html
<!-- Required styles for MDC Web -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css">

<!-- Render tab barcomponent -->
<div class="mdc-tab-bar" role="tablist">
  <div class="mdc-tab-scroller">
    <div class="mdc-tab-scroller__scroll-area">
      <div class="mdc-tab-scroller__scroll-content">
        <button class="mdc-tab mdc-tab--active" role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
          <span class="mdc-tab__content">
            <span class="mdc-tab__icon material-icons" aria-hidden="true">favorite</span>
          </span>
          <span class="mdc-tab-indicator mdc-tab-indicator--active">
            <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
          </span>
          <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Required MDC Web JavaScript library -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
```